# Why doesn't the FileNameSetter button work in my DialogInput?

Tags: dialog-window

I am new to *Mathematica*, so it's probably a small error but I can't figure it out.

Here is the code :

```
DialogInput[{TextCell["Choose your folder:"], InputField[Dynamic[x]], 
  FileNameSetter[Dynamic[x], "Directory"], 
  DefaultButton[DialogReturn[x]]}]
```

When I click on the browse button, nothing happen. Then, when I click on OK, the file system browsing window appears.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another way to get around the fact that the kernel will block until `DialogReturn` is evaluated is to use `Method -> "Preemptive"`:

```
DialogInput[{TextCell["Choose your folder:"],
  InputField[Dynamic[x]], 
  FileNameSetter[Dynamic[x], "Directory", Method -> "Preemptive"], 
  DefaultButton[DialogReturn[x]]}]
```

Comment: It seem that now `Automatic` method know what to.

Comment: @Kuba It seems to work in V9, too, even though it gives an error message.  No error message in V10. (No change indicated in the documentation, so they consider this a minor fix, I guess.)  Odd that the default behavior is not the same as `Automatic`.

Comment: Yes, it seems you have to know what you want and always place it explicitly if you want things to work :)

Answer (score 2):

Mathematica "freezes" until you press the dialog return. This is by design for `DialogInput` as far as I know. So instead use `CreateDialog`

```
CreateDialog[{TextCell["Choose your folder:"], InputField[Dynamic[x]],
   FileNameSetter[Dynamic[x], "Directory"], 
  DefaultButton[]}]
```

Comment: That's what I wanted to use. However, `CreateDialog` doesn't "freeze" and so the code go on without waiting for the input (I tried `Modal->True` but it didn't work in this case).